# Two different ways of calculating MAD return different solutions

Tags: r, mad

I have a large dataframe `data` with following columns:

```
date        time        orig      new
2001-01-01  00:30:00    345       856
2001-01-01  00:32:43    4575      9261
2001-01-01  00:51:07    6453      2352
...
2001-01-01  23:57:51    421       168
2001-01-02  00:06:14    5612      3462
...
2001-01-31  23:49:11    14420     8992
2001-02-01  00:04:32    213       521
...
```

I want to calculate the monthly aggregated MAD, which can be calculated by $\textrm{MAD} = \frac{\sum|\textrm{orig}-\textrm{new}|}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of entries in one month. Ideally, at the end, I want the solutions (dataframe) in a following form:

```
month       mad
2001-01-01  7452.124
2001-02-01  3946.734
2001-03-01  995.938
...
```

I calculated the monthly MAD in two different ways.

**Approach 1**

I grouped `data` by month and took an average of the summed absolute differences (which is a "mathematical" way to do it, as I explained):

```
data %>%
   group_by(
       month = lubridate::floor_date(date, 'month')
   ) %>%
   summarise(mad = mean(abs(orig - new)))
```

**Approach 2**

I grouped `data` by hour and got the MAD grouped by hour, and then re-grouped it by month and took an average. This is counter-intuitive, but I used the hourly grouped dataframe for other analyses and tried computing the monthly MAD from this dataframe directly.

```
data_grouped_by_hour <- data %>%
   group_by(
        day = lubridate::floor_date(date, 'day'),
        hour = as.POSIXlt(time)$hour
   ) %>%
   summarise(mad = mean(abs(orig - new)))

data_grouped_by_hour %>%
   group_by(
       month = lubridate::floor_date(date, 'month')
   ) %>%
   summarise(mad = mean(mad))
```

As hinted from the post title, these approaches return different values. I assume my first approach is correct, as it is more concise and follows the accurate concept, but I wonder why the second approach does not return the same value.

Any mathematical or programming explanation is appreciated.

Comment: No idea about R, sorry, but does "month" meanly monthly date, e.g. December 2022, or month of year, e.g. December in any year?

Comment: @NickCox monthly date, so December 2022, for example. In my `data`, I would see December 2001, December 2002, December 2003, and so on separately.

Comment: That makes sense; I just wondered how the syntax worked here as it is surely ambiguous as read, although presumably documented clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74810626/calculating-mad-in-two-different-ways-in-r-return-different-results), both conceptually and practically.

---

Just to clarify the mathematics behind this: retrieving the mean and the mean of means (average of averages) are two different metrics, and hence explains the difference between two approaches.

In order to get the same value in Approach 2, one must use the weighted mean.